# How to set Content-Type in spring-mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am wondering how I can set the `Content-Type` header when using a template engine.

I know there is a default configuration that can be set at the `ViewResolver` configuration, but I want, per method, set a different content type (html or json)

I tried using the produces attribute from `@GetMapping` but it is not used in the View object.

AFAIK, the `Content-Type` is set per View and the View is common across all the queries :(

Answer (score 0):

you can pass HttpServletResponse to your method and set its content type

```
 @GetMapping
 public Entity getEntity (HttpServletResponse response) {
      response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```